# GORM cannot create new entity using addTo

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I have a class SheetLayout with the following:

```
private String size
private int xPosition
private int yPosition

private Sheet sheet
private Report report

static belongsTo=[sheet : Sheet]
```

and a class Sheet with the following:

```
@Id
private String id

private Date created = new Date()
private Date modified
private String title
private int sheetIndex
private String type

private Dashboard dashboard

static hasMany = [sheetLayouts : SheetLayout, slicersWidgets : SlicerWidget]

static belongsTo=[dashboard : Dashboard]
```

Now I am trying to save SheetLayout in any possible way (with or without Sheet) and it doesn't work.
One of my the options I tried:

```
def testsl(){
        Sheet s = Sheet.findById("AAAAAaaaaaAAAaaaAA")
        SheetLayout sl = new SheetLayout()
        sl.setxPosition(0)
        sl.setyPosition(1)
        sl.setSize("satas")
        s.addToSheetLayouts(sl)
        s.save(flush:true)

    }
```

and it's just not working :(

any idea?

Comment: You don't need `private Sheet sheet` if you have `static belongsTo=[sheet : Sheet]`. But i don't know if it fixes the problem

Comment: Thank I was trying but it's still not helping.
I think this is because I also have entity Report which has static hasMany = [sheetLayouts : SheetLayout]
now when I am trying to save SheetLayout it's ot working because I need to have value in report_id in my SheetLayout object.

Comment: Could you post the error stacktrace if there is one?

Comment: And did you try printing out some data? Is the sheet found? also when saving, write `...save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` so it will show the errors while saving

Comment: You should remove all of those occurrences of `private`.  Removing them will give you private fields plus public getters and setters, which is what you want for all of your persistent properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> GORM cannot create new entity using addTo

I don't think that is true.  The following works:

Sheet.groovy

```
class Sheet {
    // consider using GORM auto timestamp properties for these Dates...
    Date created
    Date modified

    String title
    int sheetIndex
    String type

    static hasMany = [sheetLayouts : SheetLayout]
}
```

SheetLayout.groovy

```
class SheetLayout {
    String size
    int xPosition
    int yPosition

    Sheet sheet

    static belongsTo = [sheet : Sheet]
}
```

Code to persist instances:

```
    def now = new Date()
    Sheet s = new Sheet(created: now, modified: now, title: 'Some Title', sheetIndex: 42, type: 'wilbur')
    SheetLayout sl = new SheetLayout()
    sl.setxPosition(0)
    sl.setyPosition(1)
    sl.setSize("satas")
    s.addToSheetLayouts(sl)
    s.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

You could also do something like this:

```
    def now = new Date()
    Sheet s = new Sheet(created: now, modified: now, title: 'Some Title', sheetIndex: 42, type: 'wilbur')
    s.addToSheetLayouts(xPosition: 0, yPosition: 1, size: 'satas')
    s.save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
```

I suggest you inspect the `errors` property after attempting to save the instance and/or use `failOnError:true`.

EDIT:

I just re-read your example and it looks like your `SheetLayout` class has a `report` property that you are not initializing.  Unless you have configured that with `nullable: true`, that will be part of your problem.